# How to reduce SDK Size in MAUI

Tags: android, maui, anyline

My application uses Anyline to scan electricity meters. It uses only one module (energy) and it would be nice to remove all unused stuff. According to the Anyline documentation, it is possible to decrease size of their sdk by removing unnecessary modules. I wonder if that is achievable in MAUI? Thanks for any help

I found info how we can do it on Android (native) and I would expect that something similar is possible in MAUI

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        aaptOptions {
            // Enter any modules into "used_modules" you would like to keep and use
            def used_modules = [
                    "module_energy",
                    "module_id",
                    "module_barcode"
            ].toList()

            // Below is the full list of modules
            def all_modules = [
                    "module_anyline_ocr",
                    "module_barcode",
                    "module_document",
                    "module_energy",
                    "module_id",
                    "module_license_plate",
                    "module_tire"
            ].toList()

            // All used modules are kept, the rest are discarded (to shrink your app)
            all_modules.removeAll(used_modules)

            def all_removed_modules = all_modules.join(":")
            ignoreAssetsPattern all_removed_modules
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/linking?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs